# Hiding list view context menu for internet facing site

Tags: 2013, custom-actions, personalization, internet-sites

I need to hide the context menu for standard list views on Sharepoint 2013. I have an internet facing site, using the standard list views only customized from CSS, JS, JSLink, etc. and also on tabular *styles* of the view. On SP2013 the right-click on any list item give us the context menu item, which my client didn't want at all on the internet facing site collection.

All my searches on the subject returns with tips on hiding or adding one item of the menu, but I couldn't find nothing on disabling at all the right-click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the views of the lists and remove the field with property *linked to item with edit menu*. Instead you may use the field with *linked to item* property.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think on it because the right-click operation works on any space of the row, not precisely on the field _with edit menu_, but it seems to be the solution and I'll come back when tried.

Comment: Actually the view was personalized by scripting using `SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides`, so in our case we have the call `oncontextmenu='return ShowCallOutOrECBWrapper(this, event, false)'` that must be removed. Of course that situation wasn't described on the original question, and the answer to the implied original described situation was correct.